# Lost in Backbone's events

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

There is something that I do not understand well in backbone's event. 
When I defined a view, the "el" element is the element in which my views will be render? (I hope I'm still right here)
And when I put events on the view, backbone listen them only when the event is fired in the "el" element?

In my case I want to create a new view that will be render on click event on an element outside my "el" element.
I'm on the wrong way to it or this is not the good solution ?

Comment: I want to re-render my view with new filter contains in the data-attributes of my clicked elements witch is outside the views (outside the "el").

Comment: So you want to listen to events that are outside the scope of the views element? You could create another view that deals with the events that are within the scope of its element.

Comment: Yes, it's what i want to do, I will try that.